# Display the link of a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to manually display the link of a custom taxonomy term that I have created. The taxonomy is 'event-themes' and the term is 'Boat'. Here's my code:

```
<?php $themeOne = array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'event-themes',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'boat-theme'
                )
            )
        );
        ?>
        <li><a href=""><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/eventSearch/theme-onFoot.png" /><span><?php echo $themeOne; ?></span></a></li>
```

I'm not very familiar with PHP so I guess I'm probably missing something very obvious here, but my main aim is to simply 'handpick' the taxonomy term I want, and display a link to the page displaying all posts/pages under it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are just storing an "array" in the variable $themeOne. The code you should be using to make the query is:

```
$themeOne = new WP_Query(array(
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'event-themes',
        'terms' => 'boat-theme'
    )
)
));
```

The result should be an array of objects. You can then access these using the following code:

```
foreach($themeOne as $term){
    print $term->slug;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing functions. The tax query array is intented to modify the query that affect the loop.
To just manually print the term link you can do:

```
<li><a href=""><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/eventSearch/theme-onFoot.png" /><span><?php echo get_bloginfo('url').'/event-themes/boat-theme'; ?></span></a></li>
```